# If $X=A-F/3$, how to calculate $E(X)$, $Var(X)$ and $P(X≥5)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

### The exercise

An examination of questions with multiple answers, has 20 questions, and each question consists of 4 alternatives, one of which is correct.

The student's score is a random variable $ X $ given by $ X = A-\dfrac{F}{3} $,

where $A$ is the random variable "number of hits" and $F$ is the random variable "number of failures".

If a student answers at random all the questions:

- a) What is the distribution of variable $A$?
- b) What is the expectation and variance of $X$?
- c) What is the probability that the student will get at least $5$
  points in the exam?

### What I did

**a)** $A$~$B(20,1/4)$

*I assumed that $F$~$B(20,3/4)$, so that:*

- $E(A)=(20)*(1/4)=5$
- $E(F)=(20)*(3/4)=15$
- $Var(A)=(20)*(1/4)*(1-(1/4))=15/4$
- $Var(F)=(20)*(3/4)*(1-(3/4))=15/4$

**If part (a) is ok (maybe not). How can I resolve parts (b) and (c)?** Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for both as below. You should be able to work it out.

$b)\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[X] = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[A] - \dfrac{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[F]}{3}$

$Var[X] = Var[A] + \dfrac{Var[F]}{9} - \dfrac{2Cov(A,F)}{3} $

$c) P(X\geq5) = 1 - P(X<5)$

Comment: Could you explain why they are independent $A$ and $F$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Of course I understand now. Another question: Why is $P(X \geq 5) = 1 - P(X \leq 5)$? I thought it was $P(X \geq 5) = 1 - P(X < 4)$

Comment: It's not. I have just edited.

Comment: And $1 - P(X < 5) = 1 - P(X ≤ 4)$? Thanks.

Comment: Correct, this is an alternative way of writing it.